# Adding TextView to RelativeLayout inside AsyncTask does not work

Tags: android, textview, android-relativelayout

I am adding few TextViews to a RelativeLayout. I have extended RelativeLayout. I could add the TextView in the constructor definition. I could see the item on the viw. But the same code, when I use in onPostExecute of AyncTask or use post() method, TextView is not seen added to the layout. Same coe is executed both place. I just changed the top margin.

Here is my code

```
TextView tv = new TextView(context);
    addView(tv);


    tv.setHeight(49);

    tv.setWidth(100);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params.leftMargin = (int) 0;
    params.topMargin = (int) 600;
    tv.setLayoutParams(params);
```

================ Implementation ================================

```
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        DateDetailsScrollView sc = new DateDetailsScrollView(container.getContext());

        new SyncInThread().execute(sc);
        return sc;
    }
```

================= AsyncTask ===================================

```
private static class SyncInThread extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, String> {

    private ArrayList<EVT> _mEvents = new ArrayList<EVT>();
    DateDetailsScrollView _lv = null;

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Object... cal) {
        _lv = (DateDetailsScrollView)cal[0];

        //The SQL cannot be shared here... Please forgive me.
        boolean f = cursor.moveToFirst();
        while(f) {
            EVT evt = new EVT();
            evt.loadFromCursor(cursor);
            f = cursor.moveToNext();
            _mEvents.add(evt);
            cc++;
        }
        return "";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        for(EVT ev : _EVT) {
            _lv.addEvent(ev);
        }

    }

}


public class DateDetailsScrollView extends ScrollView {
    private EventRelativeLayout _mEventLayout = null;

    public DateDetailsScrollView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        _mEventLayout = new EventRelativeLayout(context);
        ll.addView(_mEventLayout);
        LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(context);
        ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        addView(ll);
    }


    public void addEvent(final VEVENT evt) {
            _mEventLayout.addEvent(evt);
            invalidate();
            this.refreshDrawableState();
    }
}



    public class EventRelativeLayout extends RelativeLayout {


public EventRelativeLayout(Context context) {
    //This works fine.
    super(context);
    TextView tv = new TextView(context);
    addView(tv);

    int[] colors = { 0xFF052d42, 0xFF096da0 };
    GradientDrawable drawable = new GradientDrawable(
            GradientDrawable.Orientation.TOP_BOTTOM, colors);

    tv.setBackgroundColor(0xFF290202);
    tv.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);
    tv.setHeight(49);

    tv.setWidth(100);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params.leftMargin = (int) 0;
    params.topMargin = (int) 100;
    tv.setLayoutParams(params);

}

public void addEvent(EVT evt) {



    TextView tv = new TextView(getContext());
    addView(tv);

    int[] colors = { 0xFF052d42, 0xFF096da0 };
    GradientDrawable drawable = new GradientDrawable(
            GradientDrawable.Orientation.TOP_BOTTOM, colors);

    tv.setBackgroundColor(0xFF290202);
    tv.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);
    tv.setHeight(100);

    int dm = em -eh;
    int dh = eh - sh;
    if( dm < 0) {
        dm += 60;
        dh--;
    }

    tv.setWidth(100);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params.leftMargin = 0;
    params.topMargin = 600;
    tv.setHeight(49);
    tv.setLayoutParams(params);


}
```

}

Comment: that is a pretty large top margin. try setting it to something smaller and see what happens

Comment: 600 is not the actual margin. Initially had it 10. This is the test code with one TextView I created to see if the behavior improves.

Answer (score 0):

I got the issue. It was a programmatic mistake and due to a wrong calculation, the veiw was added to a different page.